# VLV search request: Unavailable Critical Extension: The search results cannot be sorted because the given search request is not indexed

Tags: opendj

First, it seems this isn't related to unindexed-search privilege.I try ROOT DN user, same problem.

My Case:

I have 5000 entries of user, each entry contains "xxx@XXX.com" in the "mail" attribute. 
And I have a VLV with sort order: +uid +cn +mail

I try the filter "(mail=*.com*)" in VLV, trying to get a paged result, with total count returned. I understand that returned values will exceed 4000 limit. And I understand that SSS is very expensive request(this is admin, so this operation won't be too often).

My question is: in this case, should I accept it and tell the user to narrow down the search result, or there are any possible solutions to solve this?

Thanks,

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

No this is not related to the unindexed privilege, but to internal administrative limits.
VLV requests (and sort requests) will work without proper indexing only if they are processing less than 4000 entries.
Otherwise, a proper VLV Index is required, and to be used it must match all parameters of the search query: base, scope, filter and sort parameters.